# The param of func upper_bound?

Tags: c++, function, debugging, gcc, constants

Code:

```
#include "inc.h"  
#include <string>  
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class tt{
    public:
        tt(int i): i(i) {}
        int i;
        bool operator < (const tt &r) 
        {
            return i < r.i;
        }

};



int test_lower_bound()
{
    vector<tt> a;
    a.push_back(tt(1));
    a.push_back(tt(2));
    a.push_back(tt(3));
    a.push_back(tt(4));
    a.push_back(tt(5));

    vector<tt>::iterator result = lower_bound(a.begin(), a.end(), tt(3));
    cout << result->i << endl;
    return 0;
}

int test_upper_bound()
{
    vector<tt> a;
    a.push_back(tt(1));
    a.push_back(tt(2));
    a.push_back(tt(3));
    a.push_back(tt(4));
    a.push_back(tt(5));

    vector<tt>::iterator result = upper_bound(a.begin(), a.end(), tt(3));
    cout << result->i << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)  
{  
    test_lower_bound();
    return 0;  
}
```

When compiled, it produces this error:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/algorithm:62,
                 from main.cc:4:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘_FIter std::upper_bound(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<tt*, std::vector<tt, std::allocator<tt> > >, _Tp = tt]’:
main.cc:45:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:2542: error: passing ‘const tt’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool tt::operator<(const tt&)’ discards qualifiers
```

From the result , we can see that `upper_bound` has an error but `lower_bound` does not, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
bool operator < (const tt &r) { return i < r.i; }
```

to this:

```
bool operator < (const tt &r) const { return i < r.i; }
```

since you need to mark your operator as `const`, in order to be able to operate on a `const` operand.

---

"Why does the error show up for `upper_bound` but not for `lower_bound`?"

If you check the standard of [`upper_bound`](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/upper_bound.html), it says:

> `upper_bound` returns the furthermost iterator `i` in `[first, last)` such that, for every iterator `j` in `[first, i), comp(value, *j)` is `false`.

Now, [`lower_bound`](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/lower_bound.html) on the other hand mentions:

> `lower_bound` returns the furthermost iterator `i` in `[first, last)` such that, for every iterator `j` in `[first, i), comp(*j, value)` is `true`.

So both functions will use your `operator <` (if you check the standard more closely, they would only use that operator in any case). So what changes?

The order of the arguments!

The problem is that `tt &r` is `const`, and in `upper_bound`'s case, it's called like:

```
comp(value, *j)
```

Here, `*j` will be your const argument.

While in `lower_bound`'s case, like:

```
comp(*j, value)
```

Here, `value` will be your const argument. This is the reason for the compilation error.

Comment: I don't think this is actually implementation-dependent.  The Standard specifies `lower_bound` returns an iterator `i` where `*j < value` for every `j` before `i`, and `upper_bound` returns an iterator `i` where `!(value < 
 *j)` for every `j` before `i`, and `value` is a `const T&`.  So the order and constness of arguments to `operator<` is exactly specified.

Comment: `lower_bound`, like most of the Standard algorithms, will *never* use `operator>`, only `operator<`.